# Android Spinner - Selected Value text is not aligning correctly

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to implement RtoL functionality in my application. The problem I'm having is with the Android Spinner. I have applied styled to the spinner to align everything as `start`. This is working fine for the spinner items, but not for the selected text in the spinner. But when a new value is changed, the alignment fixes itself (aligns to right).

Below are the styles I have for the Spinner:

```
<style name="spinnerStyle" parent="android:Widget.DeviceDefault.Spinner">
    <item name="android:gravity">start</item>
    <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerMode">dropdown</item>
    <item name="android:paddingStart">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">start</item>
    <item name="android:textAlignment">viewStart</item>
    <item name="android:paddingEnd">0dp</item>
</style>
```

This is what the spinner alignment is like when the view is first entered (with value already selected).

[image]

After I selected a new value, the alignment fixes itself:

[image]

Any ideas how I can fix that for the entry scenario?

Comment: Your style works fine. Can you post your spinner's xml?

Comment: @mTak this is using react-native

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize the ArrayAdapter, just use the android.R.layout.item1 for 
Spinner to show each item.

```
    spinner = ((Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner));

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("Djibouti");
    list.add("Egypt");
    ArrayAdapter adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            android.R.id.text1, list);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter2);
```

Comment: I'm using react-native to handle the view creation.

Comment: @RickyDavis  Sorry, there is nothing i can do then